# Constraint based on a FK relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, check-constraints

Structure of two tables with fields that are of importance:

```
TableA: Id (PK), Type
TableB: Id (PK), TableAId (FK), ReferenceId (Self-reference key)
```

I need to have a constraint which will say:

TableB ReferenceId column CAN and MUST contain a value ONLY IF TableAId value points to a record whose Type value > 1.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can do this with an INSERT/UPDATE trigger. That's the only way I can think to do it if you want the enforcement to be within SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method that doesn't require triggers had data redundancy.

Put the `type` column in TableB, along with a constraint there.  And add an additional unique key to TableA for the foreign key:

```
create table tableA (
    id int primary key,
    type int,
    constraint unq_type_id unique (type, id)
);

create table tableB (
    id int primary key,
    type int,
    tableAID int,
    constraint fk_tableB_type_tableAID foreign key (type, tableAID) references tableA(type, id),
    constraint chk_type check (type > 1)
);
```

This is a hack, but it does accomplish what you want without triggers.

A variation on this method doesn't require repeating `type` in both tables, but it does require additional columns:

```
create table tableA (
    id int primary key,
    type int,
    typeIsValid as (case when type > 1 then 1 else 0 end) persisted,
    constraint unq_type_id unique (typeIsValid, id)
);

create table tableB (
    id int primary key,
    tableAID int,
    typeIsValid as (1),
    constraint fk_tableB_typeIsValid_tableAID foreign key (typeIsValid, tableAID) references tableA(type, id) persisted
);
```

This even works in [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a91ac).